# What Keys/Certs need to be placed at Server/Client Side in HTTPS Connection

Tags: apache, openssl

I need to check HTTPS working on my local Machine . I am using Openssl S_client for that .
I have Cert/keys  files with me generated with OPENSSL in CentOS .
I am using Apache Server on Windows . I am able to connect succesfully for self-signed certs 
but am getting issues with CA signed cases.

Can anybody please answer me the following questions

What files i needed to place in Apache Directory . I have placed CA cert , CA signed Cert , server Private Key in Apache directory

And on the client Side i.e. CentOS  i have directory having CA cert , CA signed Client cert , Client Private key.

I am using the below command that works fine for self-signed Certs (with No CA ) 
openssl s_client -connect client_IP:8443 -CAfile server-selfsigned.pem

openssl s_client -connect client_IP:8444 -key client.key -cert selfsigned-client.pem -CAfile server-selfsigned.pem

but with CA signed certificates am confused what files i need to place at Apache and what files are need at Client (cent OS) side for creating a connection

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Depends on kind of Authentication you are doing if you are doing. I used Apache Tomcat as server on my machine and i didn't place any File in Tomcat directory . I place only JKS files and that contains all necessary cert and Placed them in Tomcat root Drectory..

I know may be my reply seems to be tough for anybdy to understand but can u modify your question and put some more details in that .??